# Powershell Grabbing folder structure and rights

Tags: powershell

I currently have a yearly folder structure that I am trying to implement. But people add new folders every year. Is it possible to grab all folders (but not files) and there rights at a certain level? Right now I grab specific folders using this:

```
#Get and Set the ACL to the new years folder structure
    foreach ($currentFolder in (Get-Content .\folders.txt)) {
    md $currentFolder  # Create Folder
    Get-ACL $currentFolder.Replace("16-17", "15-16") | Set-ACL $currentFolder
}
```

But is it possible to grab all the folders within a certain level instead of specifying a specific folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Robocopy. Its fast, its easy to use.

> robocopy Source Destination /mir Mirror /sec Copy permissions /secfix
>   fix folders with same name permission in destination /e copy empty
>   directories /xf exclude files /lev:3 go 3 levels deep

```
(robocopy "C:\Users\" "C:\test\" /mir /sec /secfix /e /xf * /LEV:3)
```

Comment: Yup that's true, the funny thing is i just suggested Robocopy a few minutes ago on powershell.org forums :). Good post!

Comment: LOL please up my post then :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$folders =  Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Recurse -Directory -Depth 2
foreach ($currentFolder in $folders) {
        Get-ACL $currentFolder
```

}

Get all the folders (recursively) within c:\temp to a depth of 2

Comment: depth of 2? will only go two levels?

Comment: Yes it will, you can set it to whatever.
ArcSet is correct , RoboCopy is a better tool to do this.